# hosts file mapping to access domain on SSL

Tags: dns, mapping, host

what's the differences between mapping mydomain, mydomain.com, www.mydomain.com in the hosts file?

I tried to access https://www.mydomain.com and figured out that the only mapping works for it is to map www.mydomain.com, mapping mydomain or mydomain.com in the host file doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

For the IP mapping in the `hosts` file, these are just different names and have nothing to do with each other.

**EDIT:**
Normally, the computer tries to append the local domain name to the names in the file in order to try to match the name, i. e. if you would work at Microsoft, then ".microsoft.com" would be appended to each name not containing a domain already.

But, apart from that and the case insensitivity, names are matched as they are.

Comment: so when looking at the mapping, it actually does the exact name match?

Comment: Yes. However, as host names are case insensitive, it does a case insensitive match. But apart from that, it is an exact match.